# How to handle redirection when login Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am doing performance testing. I have a URL abc.com it redirects to http://github.com for login. Because abc.com is registered in Github. What will be the approach to login into the application with Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

It's called [OAuth](https://oauth.net/2/) and you need to implement the required authorization flow, most probably [Authorization Code Grant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1), however it depends on how your "abc.com" is exactly integrated with Github.

All the information on possible options and flows is listed on [Github website](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps) so you either need to ask around what exact flow is being used or inspect the traffic from your browser using your browser developer tools or external sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or https://www.wireshark.org/

Actually it's only matter of passing correct parameters to Github `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize` and `https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token` endpoints and [correlating](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/) the dynamic values using suitable JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors).